# JavaScript: How to retrieve a random item (anchored to another item) from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, random

I'm starting to learn simple things in javascript.

I have a form (html) with multiple text fields, where the user must enter names (max 10) and then be able to generate two groups of 5 people when the button is clicked. Here my example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
You <font color="red">*</font>
</td>
<td><input id="you"/></td>
<td><input id="yourpartner"/></td>
<td> Your Partner <br><font color="red">WARNING: Let it blank if it doesnt exist!</font></td>

</tr>
<td>Partners (1-2)</td>
<td><input id="s1dq" title="Partner 1" /></td>
<td><input id="s2dq" title="Partner 2" /></td>
<td><font color="red">WARNING: Let it blank if it doesnt exist!</font></td>
<tr>
<td>Partners (3-4)</td>
<td><input id="s3dq" title="Partner 3" /></td>
<td><input id="s4dq" title="Partner 4" /></td>
<td><font color="red">WARNING: Let it blank if it doesnt exist!</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Partners (5-6)</td>
<td><input id="s5dq" title="Partner 5" /></td>
<td><input id="s6dq" title="Partner 6" /></td>

<td><font color="red">WARNING: Let it blank if it doesnt exist!</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Partners (7-8)</td>
<td><input id="s7dq" title="Partner 7 em DuoQ." /></td>
<td><input id="s8dq" title="Partner 8 em DuoQ com o anterior." /></td>
<td><font color="red">WARNING: Let it blank if it doesnt exist!</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Remaining People<br>
<font color="red">WARNING: One person per line!</font><br>
<font color="red">WARNING: Min 2 or Max 9 persons!</font></td>
<td><textarea id="people" rows="9" cols="16" title="1 person per line"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Until now, I keep **all the names in one array**, but not idea if it will be the best way for this problem.

Problem 1: I need to get the names from this array and distribute between two groups of five randomly (here I suppose I need another 2 array). But there is one small exception. When the user enters the names he has the possibility to decide whether to keep two names together, so that they can be on the same group.

Can you help me on **how to randomly distribute them between 2 groups** and if someone has a partner **how to keep  them together in the same group**?

Problem 2: Assume for example that a group already has four people. If I get a random person whose user wants to keep together with another person, obviously one of them can not join the group that only has 4 people, otherwise they will be separate.

Can you help me with some code?
Thank you!

JavaScript Code:
I know there is some error when i add the remaining people to my array.
I skipped the structures of decision because it is the least for now 
but here you have..

```
var randomTeam = new Array();
var firstTeam = new Array();
var secondTeam = new Array();

randomTeam[0] = document.getElementById('id="you"').value;
randomTeam[1] = document.getElementById('id="yourpartner"').value;

randomTeam[2] = document.getElementById('id="s1dq"').value;
randomTeam[3] = document.getElementById('id="s2dq"').value;
randomTeam[4] = document.getElementById('id="s3dq"').value;
randomTeam[5] = document.getElementById('id="s4dq"').value;
randomTeam[6] = document.getElementById('id="s5dq"').value;
randomTeam[7] = document.getElementById('id="s6dq"').value;
randomTeam[8] = document.getElementById('id="s7dq"').value;
randomTeam[9] = document.getElementById('id="s8dq"').value;

var lines = document.getElementById('id="people"').val().split('\n');;
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    randomTeam[i] = lines[i];
}
```

Comment: show the javascript code too...

Comment: You need to get the logic before you write the code. How do you address problem 2?

Comment: Christophe I do not know how to solve it, thats why I'm here.
I need something to tell me that an item is associated with another. Dont know how...
aldanux sorry completly forgot that. Remember that user may or may not create partners.

Comment: BTW out of 10, if you make team of 5, one must be separated from its partner. your requirement fails here

Comment: suggest you develop this a little further without worrying about keeping pairs together. Learn how to get the basic interface working first.  What you are asking for is advanced logic, built on top of a beginner level very primitive skeleton

Comment: MAybe i wasnt so clear.
PArtners are an option. User dont need to fill all the fields. Just in case they have partners. All others must be placed on that areatext.

Anyways if you think its impossible to make this, at least let me know how to make a simple random, cause i dont know what formula i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a basic structure.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh6C7/2/)

Hope it would help you. One mistake in your syntax is

```
document.getElementById('id="you"').value;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('you').value;
```

Comment: Wow! Didnt know that we could make this: 

randomTeam[0] = [document.getElementById('you').value, document.getElementById('yourpartner').value];

Still have the problem 2. I have one group with 6 people and the other with 4. 

But i will work on understanding what you did and i will try to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: For that, you can divide four arrays in 2 each, and divide the last arrays member to each team, just a suggestion. BTW if you find my answer helpful, you can accept it or can upvote it it.

Comment: Wish i could upvote it, but it seems since i new i have restriction on that. Only when i reach at 15 reputation i can upvote :S